# Ordering an aggregated query

Tags: postgresql, performance, aggregate, order-by, query-performance

I have a table consisting of a `pk`, an `id`, an integer `value` and a `type` consisting ~160,000,000 rows.
Consider these data in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(pk,id,value,type)
AS VALUES
    ( '1' , '1',  'A1' , 1 ),
    ( '2' , '1',  'A2' , 2 ),
    ( '3' , '1',  'A3' , 3 ),
    ( '4' , '1',  'A4' , 4 ),
    ( '5' , '1',  'A5' , 5 ),
    ( '6' , '2',  'B1' , 1 ),
    ( '7' , '2',  'B2' , 2 ),
    ( '8' , '2',  'B3' , 3 ),
    ( '9' , '2',  'B4' , 4 ),
    ( '10', '2',  'B5' , 5 )
;
```

I'm making a query like this:

```
SELECT
  min(pk),
  id,
  array_agg(value ORDER BY type) AS v
FROM foo
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY (array_agg(value ORDER BY type))[2] ;

 min  | id  |    array_agg    
------+-----+------------------
 pk1  | id1 | {A1,A2,A3,A4,A5}
 pk10 | id2 | {B1,B2,B3,B4,B5}
```

The table can have whatever index required (currently all single columns are btree indexed separately).
Is it possible to order this query by `array_agg[n]` (`n` between 1 to 5) using a btree index so that it orders in reasonable time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you expect to do `ORDER BY (array_agg(value ORDER BY type))[2]` on an index when `type[2]` isn't even on an index? It's a positional element  in an array construction. If you need that on the index, then normalize the `value` such that `A2` and `B2` are the same, perhaps `2`. Then you left outer join the table itself..

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    min(pk),
    id,
    array_agg(value ORDER BY type) AS v
  FROM foo
  GROUP BY id
) AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT id FROM foo WHERE value = '2' ) AS k
  USING (id)
ORDER BY k.id, min, id;
```

Comment: So in the right interpretation of the question I used `MIN("k"."value')` not `MIN("k"."id")`. And there's only one `value` for a single `type` in each group and `MIN` returns that sole `value`.